# Storing variables name using for loop

Tags: batch-file

I want to get the list of all files inside of `c:\test`. My attempt is this:

```
set loc=c:\test

for /f %%i in(dir "%loc%" /b') do (

 @set variable=%%i

echo %variable%

)
```

...but I'm getting back only one file name, n times. How to get all the files in that folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1.** The reason you get back only 1 file name all the time is that you did not `Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion`. 
**2.** Check again you code, you did not add a single quotation mark before `dir "%loc%" /b'`.
**3.** Check again your code once more, you can't stick "in" and "(" like `in(`, this will absolutely ruin your code.

```
@echo off
Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set "loc=c:\test"

for /f %%i in ('dir "%loc%" /b') do (
    set "variable=%%i"
    echo !variable!
)
```

Comment: @SidABS The extensions are there, for those doesn't have are folders.

Comment: Thanks . It works properly . now I do have another doubt . the bat file is on desktop and the files that I am looking for are in D:\Folder. Can I know how to change the directory inside the for loop .I had to do further more processing .Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable ["delayed expansion"](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html) for this to work. If it isn't enabled, variables are evaluated exactly once, when the script is parsed. This is why you get the one filename n times.

Some notes:

- Enable delayed expansion with `SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion`
- When delayed expansion is enabled, to take advantage of it, you need to use `!` instead of `%` as variable delimiter, so your `%variable%` becomes `!variable!`
- Loop variables like your `%%i` are an exception in that they will change their value even when delayed expansion is not enabled. Try `ECHO`ing `%%i` in your original script (i.e. without `SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion`) to see what I mean

**Edit:** [dark fang](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4867212/dark-fang) correctly points out syntax errors in your script, which I didn't even catch - but from the behaviour your described, these were not in your script when you were trying run it, because it would just have errored out.

In the end you get:

```
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
set loc=c:\test   
for /f %%i in ('dir "%loc%" /b') do (
    @set variable=%%i
    echo !variable!
)
```

Comment: Thanks for the in detail explanation :)